# Select item for first list<T> by comparing with another list<Y> using linq or lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, generics, ienumerable

In the below code, the result returns list of bool, whereas I am expecting it to be List of BState. This should satisfy the condition mentioned in the query.

How this can be achieved. Please can someone help here?

```
public class Client
{
public void Execute()
{
    var response = new DataResponse();

    var BStates = new List<BState>();
    var BState = new BState() { BId = 106, CurBState = new BState() { TerminalId = 0 } };
    BStates.Add(BState);
    BState = new BState() { BId = 107, CurBState = new BState() { TerminalId = 0 } };
    BStates.Add(BState);
    BState = new BState() { BId = 108, CurBState = new BState() { TerminalId = 0 } };
    BStates.Add(BState);
    BState = new BState() { BId = 109, CurBState = new BState() { TerminalId = 0 } };
    BStates.Add(BState);
    BState = new BState() { BId = 110, CurBState = new BState() { TerminalId = 0 } };
    BStates.Add(BState);
    
    response.CurBStates = BStates;
    
    var UResources = new List<UResource>();
    var UResource = new UResource() { Name = "U1", Type = RType.A, UReason = UReason.Unknown };
    UResources.Add(UResource);
    UResource = new UResource() { Name = "U2", Type = RType.A, UReason = UReason.Unknown };
    UResources.Add(UResource);
    UResource = new UResource() { Name = "101", Type = RType.B, UReason = UReason.Unknown };
    UResources.Add(UResource);
    UResource = new UResource() { Name = "102", Type = RType.B, UReason = UReason.BCM };
    UResources.Add(UResource);
    getBotAssignmentSnapshotResponse.UResources = UResources;



    var Result = response.CurBStates
                         .Select(c => response.UResources
                         .Any(u => u.Name != c.BotId.ToString()&& 
                                   c.CurBState.TerminalId == 0 &&
                                   u.Type == RType.B &&
                                   u.UReason != UReason.BCM));
                                   
}
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to do here, in English? Why are you doing `.Select(c => response.UResource`?

Comment: I have corrected my query above. Sorry for the typo mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-7.0) (Projects each element of a sequence to an `IEnumerable<T>` and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.) + `Where` combination (`Any`, as you can see returns `bool`):

```cs
var Result = response.CurBStates
    .SelectMany(c => response.UResources
        .Where(u => u.Name != c.BotId.ToString()&& 
                  c.CurBState.TerminalId == 0 &&
                  u.Type == RType.B &&
                  u.UReason != UReason.BCM));
```

P.S.

Use [collection initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) instead of "manually" calling `Add`:

```cs
var BStates = new List<BState>
{
    new BState() { BId = 106, CurBState = new BState() { TerminalId = 0 } },
    new BState() { BId = 107, CurBState = new BState() { TerminalId = 0 } },
    // ...
};
```

**UPD**

To get results exactly matching the `foreach` in the comments you ca do:

```cs
var Result = response.CurBStates
    .SelectMany(c => response.UResources
        .Where(u => u.Name != c.BotId.ToString() &&
                    c.CurBState.TerminalId == 0 &&
                    u.Type == RType.B &&
                    u.UReason != UReason.BCM)
        .Select(_ => c));;
```

If you don't need potential duplicates in the result then you need `Where` instead of `Select` in the original query:

```cs
var Result = response.CurBStates
    .Where(c => response.UResources
        .Any(u => u.Name != c.BotId.ToString() &&
                    c.CurBState.TerminalId == 0 &&
                    u.Type == RType.B &&
                    u.UReason != UReason.BCM));
```

Comment: Your query returns incorrect records. The query should return the same result as compared to the below code,

List<BotStateSnapshot> result = new List<CurBStates>();
foreach (var bSS in response.CurBStates)
{
 foreach (var uR in response.UResources)
 {
  if (u.Name != c.BotId.ToString()
   && c.CurBState.TerminalId == 0
   && u.Type == RType.B 
   && u.UReason != UReason.BCM)
  {
   result.Add(bSS);
  }
 }
}

Comment: @AMITSHELKE `List<BotStateSnapshot> result = new List<CurBStates>();` - I doubt that this even compile.

Comment: @AMITSHELKE try the updated queries.

Comment: It should be List<BState> result = new List<BState>();

Comment: How to return all records from the response.CurBStates when response.UResources is empty in the same query.